# Code deploy with Packer

Tags: amazon-web-services, packer

I am creating an AWS AMI that is provisioned with Chef using Packer. At the creation of snapshots tags of the AWS AMI, I want it to be tagged with tags that assign it to be deployed with CodeDeploy:

```
        {
            "aws:autoscaling:groupName": "Env1"
        }
```

In my JSON configuration for Packer, I am using `snapshot_tags` to define these.

The problem is that on creating the AMI, Packer fails with:

```
Build 'amazon-ebs' errored: Error adding tags to Resources ([]*string{(*string)(0xc420107170), (*string)(0xc420478758)}): InvalidParameterValue: Tag keys starting with 'aws:' are reserved for internal use
    status code: 400, request id: fef34822-b692-4225-a2eb-a1cfac33a924
```

Cannot I use CodeDeploy with Packer since I must use `aws` in the tag?

**ANSWER**:

There is no need to use a tag for an AMI to deploy with CodeDeploy. My mistake.

Answer (score 0):

Don't know about CodeDeploy, but you can never create a tag which starts with `aws:`.

> Do not use the aws: prefix in your tag names or values because it is reserved for AWS use. You can't edit or delete tag names or values with this prefix. Tags with this prefix do not count against your tags per resource limit.

See [AWS Docs: Using Tags - tag restrictions](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AWSEC2/latest/UserGuide/Using_Tags.html#tag-restrictions)

Comment: Turns out I do not need to use a Tag nor is an AMI tag related to deploying through CodeDeploy.